# Is converting boolean formulas to sum-of-products a hard problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, normal-forms

My reasoning is as follows.

1. Every boolean formula can be expressed as a sum-of-products.
2. Every sum-of-produts is a list of minterms.
3. For each minterm, there is 1 combination of inputs that satisfy the formula.

So if I have the sum-of-products representation of a boolean formula I can tell if it satisfiable.

But that is the SAT problem, which is hard.

So the hard part of the 3 step procedure above must be transforming a boolean formula into a sum of products.

Is this reasoning right?

Comment: "sum-of-products" in the sense of [GF(2)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiniteField.html), or in the sense of [the Boolean interpretation of those operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Operations)? ​ ​ ​

Comment: I mean going from (AB)+C to ABC'+ABC+ACB+ACB', which tells us there are 4 solutions to the problem. (If i am correct).

Comment: Is ABC+ACB a typo? ​ ​

Comment: No. I double counted ABC and ACB when expanding from AB+C: 
AB+C,
AC + BC,
ABC + AB'C + ABC + A'BC

Comment: In that case, ​ ​ ​ (A and B) ​ or ​ C ​ ​ ​ has 5 satisfying assignments and ​ ​ ​ (A and B and not C) ​ xor ​ (A and B and C) ​ [xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) ​ (A and C and B) ​ xor ​ (A and C and not B) ​ ​ ​ has only 2 satisfying assignments. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: So you mean DNF?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Proving that the conversion from CNF to DNF is NP-Hard](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3513/98)

Comment: Possibly related: [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/35209/98), [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/41070/98) and [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/7473/98)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.  Your "sum-of-products" is more commonly known as disjunctive normal form ([DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form)).  [It is easy to show](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3513/proving-that-the-conversion-from-cnf-to-dnf-is-np-hard) that conversion from conjunctive normal form (CNF) to DNF is NP-hard, so converting from general Boolean formulas to DNF can't be any easier.